# Pandas compare two columns from two dataframes if there is a match get value from third column convert to week number

Tags: python, pandas

truing to automate one report, but its over my current skill level, please assist if possible.
df1

```
report = {'Name':["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],'Week_Num':['','','','',''],"Week_1":['1','1','','',''],"Week_2":['','1','','1',''],"Week_3":['','','','','1'],"Week_4":['','','1','',''],"Week_5":['','','','','']}
```

df2

```
data = {'Name': ["one", "two", "four", "five", "two", "three"],
    "Dates":["03/01/2022", "09/01/2022", "13/01/2022", "21/01/2022", "01/01/2022","28/01/2022"]}
```

Now i have to match report['Name'] with data['Name'] ,if there is a match to get data["Dates"] convert data["Dates"] to week_number"Today is week 18", and increase value of report.at[match, week_number] += 1 on every match.
Expected output:

```
report = {'Name':["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"],'Week_Num':['','','','',''],"Week_1":['1','1','','',''],"Week_2":['','1','','1',''],"Week_3":['','','','','1'],"Week_4":['','','1','',''],"Week_5":['','','','','']}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `merge`:

```
data["Week_Num"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Dates"],format="%d/%m/%Y").dt.strftime("%W").astype(int).add(1)

counts = data[["Name","Week_Num"]].merge(report["Name"], how="right").set_index("Name")
output = pd.get_dummies(counts["Week_Num"]).reindex(range(1,6),axis=1,fill_value=0).groupby(level=0).sum().reindex(report["Name"]).reset_index()

>>> output
    Name  1  2  3  4  5
0    one  0  1  0  0  0
1    two  1  1  0  0  0
2  three  0  0  0  0  1
3   four  0  0  1  0  0
4   five  0  0  0  1  0
```